# Bootloader is disappeared in android things os bootable sd card after running 6-7 days on Raspberrypi3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, boot, android-things

We are using **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B** and **64 Gb SD card** with a flash image of latest **android of things version 1.0.10**. Running android things for 6-7 days continuously it gets stuck at **boot page** showing its logo only. When I went in deep in sd card files, **bootloader file** is missing there.

I also read logcats of rpi during boot. There is some difference between success and unsuccess boot logcats. 
Below one is important logcat which is different in success and unsuccess boot attampt and maybe responsible for whole problem 
**success boot attampt :**

```
[32m[    0.000000] [0mInitializing cgroup subsys cpu/sys/android_power/request_state
```

**Link of success logcat**
 "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YIzF1Up-PXgqYKXiEifFtb_1otTK_pBd"
 
**unsuccess boot attampt :**

```
[32m[    0.000000] [0mInitializing cgroup subsys cpu
```

**Link of unsuccess logcat**
  "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xcstYWo8DwAV3p8hS4GNwBYLSWPt2EnN"

These are **extra logcats** which are coming in unsuccessful boot attampt:

```
[32m[   11.995546] [33minit[0m: Service 'zygote' (pid 155) killed by signal 1
[32m[   11.995588] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'zygote' (pid 155) process group...
[32m[   11.995777] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 155 in 0ms
[32m[   11.996277] [33minit[31m: Unable to open '/sys/android_power/request_state': No such file or directory
[32m[   11.996371] [33minit[31m: Unable to write to '/sys/power/state': Function not implemented
[32m[   11.996405] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 178) process group...
[32m[   12.001926] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 178 in 5ms
[32m[   12.002192] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'cameraserver' (pid 179) process group...
[32m[   12.007793] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1047 pid 179 in 5ms
[32m[   12.008126] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'media' (pid 186) process group...
[32m[   12.016456] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1013 pid 186 in 8ms
[32m[   12.016819] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'netd' (pid 154) process group...
[32m[   12.022627] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 154 in 5ms
[32m[   12.022926] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'wificond' (pid 189) process group...
[32m[   12.028629] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1010 pid 189 in 5ms
[32m[   12.030145] [33minit[0m: Service 'netd' (pid 154) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.032128] [33minit[0m: Service 'audioserver' (pid 178) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.032225] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 160) process group...
[32m[   12.038570] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 160 in 6ms
[32m[   12.039749] [33minit[0m: Service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 160) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.040085] [33minit[0m: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 179) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.040724] [33minit[0m: Service 'media' (pid 186) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.041396] [33minit[0m: Service 'wificond' (pid 189) killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.042344] [33minit[0m: Untracked pid 157 killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.047159] [33minit[0m: Untracked pid 158 killed by signal 9
[32m[   12.050095] [33minit[0m: starting service 'zygote'...
[32m[   12.051897] [33minit[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/zygote', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[32m[   12.091729] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.zygote", "12009252547") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.092129] [33minit[0m: starting service 'netd'...
[32m[   12.099398] [33minit[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/netd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[32m[   12.099478] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.netd", "12056905047") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.099824] [33minit[0m: starting service 'audio-hal-2-0'...
[32m[   12.099942] [33minit[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/dnsproxyd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[32m[   12.101213] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.audio-hal-2-0", "12059063849") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.112233] [33minit[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/mdns', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
[32m[   12.113064] [33minit[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/fwmarkd', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
[32m[   12.131883] [33minit[0m: starting service 'audioserver'...
[32m[   12.133057] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.audioserver", "12091026505") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.133423] [33minit[0m: starting service 'cameraserver'...
[32m[   12.134846] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.cameraserver", "12092544318") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.143086] [33minit[0m: starting service 'media'...
[32m[   12.144363] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.media", "12102277651") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.148810] [33minit[0m: starting service 'wificond'...
[32m[   12.150563] [33minit[31m: property_set("ro.boottime.wificond", "12108148068") failed: property already set
[32m[   12.331600] [33mtype=1400 audit(10.379:66)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=289 comm="BootAnimation" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:bootanim:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.331635] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.279:67)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=296 comm="android.hardwar" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:hal_audio_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.332232] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.279:67)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=296 comm="android.hardwar" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:hal_audio_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.332253] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.279:68)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=296 comm="android.hardwar" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:hal_audio_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.454169] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.279:68)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=296 comm="android.hardwar" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:hal_audio_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.454196] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.409:69)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=295 comm="Binder:295_2" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.454385] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.409:69)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=295 comm="Binder:295_2" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.454400] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.409:70)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=295 comm="Binder:295_2" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.582652] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.409:70)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=295 comm="Binder:295_2" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.582682] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.539:71)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=298 comm="cameraserver" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.582868] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.539:71)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=298 comm="cameraserver" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.582883] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.539:72)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=298 comm="cameraserver" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.650384] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.539:72)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=298 comm="cameraserver" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.650412] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.599:73)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=297 comm="audioserver" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.650590] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.599:73)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=297 comm="audioserver" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.650606] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.599:74)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=297 comm="audioserver" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.799551] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.599:74)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=297 comm="audioserver" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.799577] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.749:75)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=294 comm="zygote" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.800020] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.749:75)[0m: avc: denied { write } for pid=294 comm="zygote" name="trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   12.800037] [33mtype=1400 audit(12.749:76)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=294 comm="zygote" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[32m[   13.887976] [33minit[0m: Service 'zygote' (pid 294) killed by signal 1
[32m[   13.888018] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'zygote' (pid 294) process group...
[32m[   13.888191] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 294 in 0ms
[32m[   13.888467] [33minit[31m: Unable to open '/sys/android_power/request_state': No such file or directory
[32m[   13.888538] [33minit[31m: Unable to write to '/sys/power/state': Function not implemented
[32m[   13.888575] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 297) process group...
[32m[   13.897161] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 297 in 8ms
[32m[   13.897428] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'cameraserver' (pid 298) process group...
[32m[   13.903230] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1047 pid 298 in 5ms
[32m[   13.903682] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'media' (pid 299) process group...
[32m[   13.911888] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1013 pid 299 in 8ms
[32m[   13.912291] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'netd' (pid 295) process group...
[32m[   13.919098] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 295 in 6ms
[32m[   13.919359] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'wificond' (pid 300) process group...
[32m[   13.924770] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1010 pid 300 in 5ms
[32m[   13.925920] [33minit[0m: Service 'netd' (pid 295) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.926379] [33minit[0m: Service 'audioserver' (pid 297) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.926420] [33minit[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 296) process group...
[32m[   13.933661] [33minit[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 296 in 7ms
[32m[   13.934628] [33minit[0m: Service 'audio-hal-2-0' (pid 296) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.934918] [33minit[0m: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 298) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.935437] [33minit[0m: Service 'media' (pid 299) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.936004] [33minit[0m: Service 'wificond' (pid 300) killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.936250] [33minit[0m: Untracked pid 301 killed by signal 9
[32m[   13.936359] [33minit[0m: Untracked pid 302 killed by signal 9
```

Please help me to find how to come out from bootloop.

Comment: You better show us the lines above `Service 'zygote' (pid 294) killed by signal 1`. Those contain info about the system service that failed to start.

Comment: This is the log before **zygote** which is **common** in both attempts ```[32m[    8.173438] [33mtype=1400 audit(8.129:66)[0m: avc: denied { open } for pid=287 comm="BootAnimation" path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracinceg/tra_marker" dev="tracefs" ino=47 scontext=u:r:bootanim:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_tracing:s0 tclass=file permissive=1``` I'm also attaching **links** of complete logs of both attempts for further reference in question itself.